# Styling the Busy indicator in QML 2.0

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, busyindicator

I am using Busy indicator to show intermediate progress and i want to change the color of the circles. I referred [Customizing Busy indicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-busyindicator) link but this is changing the default animation and other things. Also, It is difficult to understand because there is no explanation for the same.

I just want to change the **color** and the animations should be the same as default. please suggest.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/Styles/Base/BusyIndicatorStyle.qml) is the original style, copy that and modify it in your custom indicator

Comment: @bardao this link is for version 1.0 but i need for version 2.0. In 2.0 styles are not available for any controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `BusyIndicator` actually just uses the `palette.dark` color, you can easily change it using the following code:

```
BusyIndicator {
    palette.dark: "red"
}
```

Note that if you use the Material theme, you have to set the `Material.accent` color `Material.accent: "red"`. And perhaps similar changes apply to other themes.

*Fun fact:* I found this by looking at the QML files in the Qt folder, for me: `Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2`

Comment: if  i change the palette color the animation is not clear after some 20secs . Do you have any idea on this ? or it a QT BUG ?

Comment: That is probably a Qt Bug, there is nothing on animation in the mentioned QML file. However the [C++ code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols2/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialbusyindicator.cpp.html) doesn't seem to be very complex neither